# GNP, GDP, GNI, GNDI and their relationships?

Tags: macroeconomics, open-economy-macro

GDP - Gross Domestic Product

GNP - Gross National Product

GNI - Gross National Income

GNDI - Gross National Disposable Income

We know that GNI=GNP, and that [GNP=GDP+Net income from factor ownership abroad.](http://www.economicshelp.org/blog/3491/economics/difference-between-gnp-gdp-and-gni/)

What I don't understant is how according to IMF Balance of Payments terminology, we have that [GNDI=GDP+net primary and secondary income from abroad](https://www.imf.org/external/pubs/ft/bop/2007/pdf/chap14.pdf), when we know that [GNDI = GNI+net current transfer from abroad](https://stats.oecd.org/glossary/detail.asp?ID=1175)? 
Wouldn't this be tantamount to say that GNP=GDP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNI is simply a new name for GNP.  It is GDP plus net primary income from abroad (i.e. with primary income paid abroad treated as negative). Primary income is described in [Chapter 11 of the IMF BOP manual](https://www.imf.org/external/pubs/ft/bop/2007/pdf/chap11.pdf)

GNDI is GNI plus net secondary income from abroad (and similarly secondary income paid abroad is treated as negative).  Net secondary income from abroad is the same thing as is meant by net current transfers from abroad: see [Chapter 12 of the IMF BOP manual](https://www.imf.org/external/pubs/ft/bop/2007/pdf/chap12.pdf)